# receive image with PHP sent from FLASH

Tags: php, flash

How can I save image with PHP which was uploaded with http post using FLASH?

To upload to i'm PHP using this:

```
            var upload_to:*=new flash.net.URLRequest("url");
            fileHandler.upload(upload_to);
```

And when I print $_FILES in PHP I get:

```
           {"Filedata":{"name":"IMG_8​658 copy44.jpg","type":"applic​ation\/octet-            stream","tmp_​name":"C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\​php35.tmp","error":0,"size​":183174}}
```

so the question is, how to form a file from that $_FILES variable?: ) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't store the file in memory. It's written out to a temporary file, which you can retrieve the name/path of from the `tmp_name` value (C:\WINDOWS...). The `name` field is the filename as provided by the client (IMG_8658...);

In your case, that'd be

```
$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] <-- location of temporary file
$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] <---original filename
$_FILES['Filedata']['size'] <--- size in bytes
$_FILES['Filedata']['type'] <-- mime type, as provided by the uploader
$_FILES['Filedata']['error'] <--- error code of upload operation (0 = a-ok)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `copy($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],'your destination path');` function.

Comment: use `move_uploaded_file()` instead. There's some security issues with uploads on shared servers that m_u_f() takes into account and copy() doesn't